# Expected value and variance of estimator with a sum in the denominator

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have the following estimators:

$\hat{\theta_1} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{^{\delta}}} $ and

$\hat{\theta_2} = -\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (x_i^{^{}})} $

I want to find the expected value and variance of those estimators to determine whether they are biased and/or consistent. Yet, I'm somehow stuck on how to deal with the sum in the denominator.

$\mathbf{E}\left( \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{^{\delta}}} \right)$ = n $\mathbf{E}\left( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{^{\delta}}} \right)$

and

$\mathbf{V}\left( \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{^{\delta}}} \right) = {n}^2$ $\mathbf{V}\left( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{^{\delta}}} \right)$

The same holds for $\hat{\theta_2}$, but at this point I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is anything given regarding the distribution of the $X_i$?

Comment: Yes, the corresponding distributions are $f(x) = \theta\delta{x}^{\delta-1}e^{-\theta x \delta}$ for the first estimator and
$f(x) = \theta x^{\theta - 1}$ for the second. The X_i are i.i.d. However, why do the distributions matter? In class, we always just evaluated the bias and variance of estimators without knowing the underlying distribution. It is to be noted that we did not tread the cases above in class, I made these examples myself to exercise. To get to the corresponding estimators, i used the maximum likelihood method.

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimator in the first case is given by $\hat{\theta}_1=\frac{n}{\delta\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$ and in the second case by $\hat{\theta}_2=\frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{x_i}}$. To calculate the expectation value and variance of these estimator you will first need to find their underlying distribution (remember: $E[Y]=\int y f_Y(y)\,dx$) and for this you will need the distributions of the $X_i$.

Comment: Yes, as commented on the answer below, the correct first density is $f(x) = \theta\delta x^{\delta - 1} e^{\theta\ x^{\delta}}$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "expression" you wrote in the comment is

$$f_X(x)=\theta \delta x^{\delta-1}e^{-\delta \theta x}$$

please provide the support because i.e. if $X>0$ this is NOT a density.

Example: Set $\theta=2$ and $\delta=3$ and you get

$$\int_0^{\infty}6x^2e^{-6x}dx \ne 1$$

---

The second expression is a Beta.

$$f_X(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$$

$\theta>0$

$x \in [0;1 ]$

The ML estimator for $\theta$ you showed is wrong. The correct one is

$$\hat{\theta}=\frac{n}{\Sigma_i(-\log X_i)}$$

It is very easy to verify that

$$Y=-\log(X)\sim  Exp(\theta)$$

Thus $\Sigma_i Y_i\sim Gamma(n;\theta)$ with expectation $E(\Sigma_i Y_i)=n/\theta$

Thus, using Jensen's inequality you get

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]\ne \frac{n}{n/\theta}=\theta$$

so it is biased for $\theta$

On the other hand, as $\hat{\theta}$ is MLE, it is asymptotically unbiased and consistent for $\theta$ (these are basic properties of MLE)

If you want to calulate mean and variance of your MLE analithically it is not difficult... you have to solve some integrals connected with gamma distribution.

---

The first "modified " density is now clear: it's a Weibull. Now, assuming $\delta$ known,

$$\hat{\theta}=\frac{n}{\Sigma_x x^\delta}$$

is the MLE for $\theta$ thus it is asimptotically unbiased and consistent. To check unbiasedness let's take the likelihood

$$L(\theta)\propto \theta^n e^{-\theta \Sigma_x x^\delta}$$

$$l(\theta)=n\log\theta-\theta\Sigma_x x^{\delta}$$

The score is

$$l^*(\theta)=\frac{n}{\theta}-\Sigma_x x^{\delta}$$

Now remembering that $E(l^*)=0$ you get

$$E\Big(\frac{n}{\Sigma_x x^\delta}\Big)=\theta$$

Thus $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm sorry, you're right. I mistyped the density for the first one. The correct function is $f(x) = \theta\delta x^{\delta - 1} e^{\theta\ x^{\delta}}$. Hence, with your example we have $\int_{0}^{\infty} 6 x^{2} e^{-2 x^{3}} = 1$. Maybe I'm just confused because in class, we never had to use the actual densities to determined the expected value and variance of estimators. For example, we just solved $E(\hat\theta)$ and checked whether the resulting outcome was $E(x)$ or whether we have a bias. I guess in this case this is not possible then.

Comment: @Luca : the modified density now looks fine, it's a Weibull. See my answer for details